# Include path for executing included Makefile

Tags: python-2.7, makefile

I'm using Makefiles for a Python project. There are some Python configuration variables that I need to include in every Makefile, and the Makefiles may reside in various subdirectories within the project's root (though not more than one level deep).

In the root of the project, I created a Makefile.inc with, for example, the following contents:

```
define PYSCRIPT
from lib.custommodule import VAR1
print(VAR1)
endef
VAR1 := $(shell python -c '$(PYSCRIPT)')
```

'custommodule' lives inside a Python lib directory root of the project, and all Makefiles at the top-level that include Makefile.inc execute without errors.

In 'subdirectory/Makefile', I have:

```
include ../Makefile.inc
echo $(VAR1)
```

When I `cd subdirectory && make`, I receive the error:

```
ImportError: No module named custommodule
```

I've tried prepending the Python path  in 'Makefile.inc' (in the `define PYSCRIPT` block) to include the parent directory, thinking that 'subdirectory/Makefile' was executing '../Makefile.inc' in it's own path versus its parent path, but that didn't work either.

Am I missing something that's preventing this from working? Or is there a better way of achieving what I'm attempting to?

Answer (score 0):

What about a `Makefile.inc` with:

```
ROOTDIR ?= .

define PYSCRIPT
from lib.custommodule import VAR1
print(VAR1)
endef
export PYSCRIPT

VAR1 := $(shell PYTHONPATH=$(ROOTDIR) python -c "$$PYSCRIPT")
```

and a `subdirectory/Makefile` with:

```
ROOTDIR = ..
include $(ROOTDIR)/Makefile.inc

all:
    echo $(VAR1)
```

Not tested.

Comment: This won't work: you're trying to add a make variable assignment into the python script.

Comment: Not exactly. I add to the python script to be executed by the `$(shell ...)` call a python variable assignment. The make expansion will take place before passing the script to python. If you have clear evidence that it cannot work, please explain why.

Comment: Sure, `$(ROOTDIR)` will be expanded before python is invoked.  But the _assignment_ will be interpreted by python, not make, because you're passing the entire script to `python -c`.  You're just setting a Python variable named `PYTHONPATH` to either `.` or `..`, which is a syntax error in Python and wouldn't do what you wanted anyway.  You could do this: `$(shell PYTHONPATH=$(ROOTDIR) python -c '$(PYSCRIPT)')` (and take it out of the script).  For clear evidence, just run `python -c 'PYTHONPATH=.'` and watch it fail...

Comment: You're right PYTHONPATH shall be set by the invoking shell. I fixed my answer (and a few other problems with the original makefiles).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried the suggestion and it didn't work. I worked around the problem by exporting VAR1 in a top-level Makefile and calling `subdirectory/Makefile` from there. This isn't ideal because I can't directly call `subdirectory/Makefile`, but it does allow me to move forward until another option is worked out.